# In the vmexit, I can't get the correct DR6 register

Tags: c++

I used the hvpp project to write a routine for capturing exceptions or NMIs as follows:

void vmexit_custom_handler::handle_exception_or_nmi(vcpu_t& vp) noexcept
{

```
auto interrupt = vp.interrupt_info();
auto iv = interrupt.vector();


if (iv == ia32::exception_vector::debug)
{

    auto dr6 = read<dr6_t>();
    log("%llX", dr6);
}



base_type::handle_exception_or_nmi(vp);
```

}
If I set the DR0 register to set a read/write breakpoint on memory, then when an assembly instruction triggers this hardware breakpoint, a debug exception (int 1) will be received. In this exception, I print out DR6 and find the last 4 bits of DR6 are 0. Theoretically, if the exception is triggered by the DR0 register, the last bit of the DR6 register should be 1. This makes it impossible for the debugger inside my virtual machine to correctly determine whether the exception was triggered by a debug register. How can I solve this problem? This issue has troubled me for a long time.